# In Fusion 360 how do I select an entire 3D object, not just its sides or faces?

Tags: software, cad, fusion360

I'd like to mirror a triangular prism I made. However, whenever I select it I am only able to select the faces or sides.

Is there a way to select the whole 3D object to move or mirror it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a "select" tool in the toolbar next to "make". You can use select filters to select components, bodies and faces.

Answer (score 4):

Selecting the body in the browser will select the entire body. Clicking on the body in the viewer will only get you faces or edges.

A long click (click and hold) on the model will give you options on what to select. You can choose a face or body under "Depth" or choose a body or feature under "Parents."

Answer (score 2):

In the top left of your workspace (still inside the editor) you will have a dropdown, in that dropdown there is a folder called bodies, open that and select the body you want. You can then move the selected body.